# MATLAB - Supervised Classifcation/Segmentation

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, classification, image-segmentation

I am working with PRtools at the moment. 
I am very stuck with what I am doing.

Please could anyone guide me through on how to get from training dataset to classifier?
All the examples that I have looked at the training and testing data are generated from the same dataset, in this case, A, randomly such:

```
A=datafile(2:end,1:end-1);
labs=datafile(2:end,end);
A=dataset(A,labs);
A=setprior(A,[0.5 0.5]);
[B,C] = gendat(A,0.2);
W = pca(B,2);  % compute PCA on training set only
A2 = A*W;      % maps all data to 2D
B2 = B*W;      % maps training set to 2D
C2 = C*W;      % maps test set to 2D
figure; gridsize(50); scatterd(A2,'legend');
V = B2*ldc;    % compute classifier in 2D
plotc(V);      % plot in 2D
D = C2*V;      % classify
testc(D);      % compute error
confmat(D)     % compute confusion matrix
```

However, I have my training images of different textures. Features are computed;

```
train = dataset(double(glcm_features));     
train_label = setlabels(a, label(:,1));
```

but my test image is a combination of 2 or more textures on a single image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/37N6J.jpg

Please can anyone give me some guidance on what I need to do in order to do that? 
I am stuck because I obviously it does not have labels for the testing set, and it gives me errors saying labels expected...

Please help. 
Thank you in advance.

=======================update

What I really want to do is, how to get the program to classify the texture of within an image containing multiple textures

[image]

Answer (score 0):

First of all i don't understand what are you trying to do. However, to calculate classification errors you need to have the groundtruth/true labels with you. But as you say you don't have labels for the testing set, so you cannot compute the error.

However, usually what is done is that the training set is divided into two sets, call them training set and validation set. You train with the training set and calculate your classification error on the validation set for which you have the true labels.

Assuming your test set and train set come from the same distribution, you can generalize the errors computed on your validation set to be the expected error on test set.

Comment: Thanks so much for reply first of all. What I really want to do is, how to get the program to identify a single texture of interest within an image containing multiple textures (as shown on the link above) --------

Comment: Sorry if I misunderstand you, but what I understand from what you said here is, I can directly feed in the multiple textures images to the classifier? Like I first divide the mix texture image by mapping it to a mask of different intensities; then I get the features from all the classes and give them labels; last I randomly divide the samples into 2 sets and get the classification error from there? --------

is that what I said correct?